# how do i update column (selmanufacturers_id) from the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, management-studio-express

```
SELECT 
    'S. J. & G. FAZUL ELLAHIE (PVT) LTD.' AS CompanyName,
    'E - 46, S.I.T.E., KARACHI - 75700' AS CompanyAddress,
    'admin' login_user, 'crm.sjg.local' selhost,
    'admin' sellogin, 'sr_salereport' seltoprint,
    'SALES REPORT' selreportTitle, '' selflagType,
    'SI' selreportType, '' selfrmDate, '' seltoDate,
    '' selfromProductId, '' selac_fromProductId_ac,
    '' selbrandId, '' selcustomerId, '' selac_customerId_ac,
    '' selgodownId, '' selsmId, '' selsalesmanId, '' selcity,
    '' selarea, '' selorders_status, 'S' seldst,
    'Invoice' selgroup1, '1' selcurrencyid, 'id' seltype,
    'D' seldefUnit, '' selmanufacturers_id, 'Report' selyt0,
    CAST(docTypeId as varchar(20)) + CAST(documentId as varchar(20)) groupId1,
    [dbo].[ITL_DATE_TO_STRING_FOR_SORTING](refDate) groupTitle1, 
    '' groupId2, '' selgroup2,'' groupTitle2, * 
FROM 
    [dbo].SR_Sale(null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, N'', N'', 0, N'SI', 0, 0, 1, N'id', N'D') AS TR 
WHERE
    docType IN ('SI', 'GYM RECEIPT')
```

Comment: the query is running and ok to select the data from the table... but actually i want to update a single column (selmanufacturers_id) but I can't use the correct syntax... Please guide me with one or two columns from the above query.. the problem is to update selmanufacturers_id where products_id is equal to 9031

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general update statement

```
FROM dbo.SR_Sale
SET selmanufacturers_id ='xxx'
WHERE (TODO: add where-clause here to specify which row needs to be updated)
```

Comment: thanks, but dbo.SR_Sale is a function. I can't use update query on function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming selmanufacturers_id does not exist in [dbo].SR_Sale function but contrary to products_id.

```
    IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_SR_SALE') IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tmp_SR_SALE
    END


    SELECT  'S. J. & G. FAZUL ELLAHIE (PVT) LTD.' AS CompanyName ,
            'E - 46, S.I.T.E., KARACHI - 75700' AS CompanyAddress ,
            'admin' login_user ,
            'crm.sjg.local' selhost ,
            'admin' sellogin ,
            'sr_salereport' seltoprint ,
            'SALES REPORT' selreportTitle ,
            '' selflagType ,
            'SI' selreportType ,
            '' selfrmDate ,
            '' seltoDate ,
            '' selfromProductId ,
            '' selac_fromProductId_ac ,
            '' selbrandId ,
            '' selcustomerId ,
            '' selac_customerId_ac ,
            '' selgodownId ,
            '' selsmId ,
            '' selsalesmanId ,
            '' selcity ,
            '' selarea ,
            '' selorders_status ,
            'S' seldst ,
            'Invoice' selgroup1 ,
            '1' selcurrencyid ,
            'id' seltype ,
            'D' seldefUnit ,
            '' selmanufacturers_id ,
            'Report' selyt0 ,
            CAST(docTypeId AS VARCHAR(20)) + CAST(documentId AS VARCHAR(20)) groupId1 ,
            [dbo].[ITL_DATE_TO_STRING_FOR_SORTING](refDate) groupTitle1 ,
            '' groupId2 ,
            '' selgroup2 ,
            '' groupTitle2 ,
            *
    INTO #tmp_SR_SALE FROM    [dbo].SR_Sale(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, N'', N'', 0, N'SI', 0, 0, 1,
                          N'id', N'D') AS TR
    WHERE   docType IN ( 'SI', 'GYM RECEIPT' )

    UPDATE #tmp_SR_SALE
    SET selmanufacturers_id = 'value here'
    WHERE products_id = 9031

    SELECT * FROM #tmp_SR_SALE
```

Comment: if i run this query, won't i lost the previous table along with the data?

Comment: this will just update selmanufacturers_id virtually on  #tmp_SR_SALE, the data in [dbo].SR_Sale function will be the same and intact.